# JPA Persist not persisting children entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with persisting children entities even though I'm using a *CascadeType.PERSIST*. When i add new children object to a parent it's persisted but it's fields are made null.

My Entities:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class Portfolio {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String ownerEmail;

    private Long roomId;

    private Double startingCash;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<PortfolioState> states;
}
```

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class PortfolioState {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Date fromDate;

    private Date to;

    private Double cash;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private List<Position> positions;

}
```

When the following lines of code get executed, PortfolioState get's persisted with all except id as null.

```
        /*Adding a new PortfolioState to Portofolio's states */
        System.out.println(" Portfolio : " + portfolio.toString());
        Portfolio savedPortfolio = portfolioRepository.save(portfolio);
        System.out.println(" Saved portfolio : " + savedPortfolio.toString());
        System.out.println(" Portfolio object  after saving " + portfolio.toString());
```

```
 Portfolio : Portfolio(id=1, ownerEmail=jasiekziom@gmail.com, roomId=1, startingCash=1000.0, states=[PortfolioState(id=2, fromDate=2020-01-01 00:00:00.0, to=Mon Jan 06 00:00:00 CET 2020, cash=300.0, positions=[Position(id=3, ticker=MSFT, quantity=2), Position(id=4, ticker=AAPL, quantity=3)]), PortfolioState(id=null, fromDate=Tue Jan 07 00:00:00 CET 2020, to=Sun Sep 14 02:00:00 CEST 3197, cash=290.28, positions=[Position(id=null, ticker=MSFT, quantity=2), Position(id=null, ticker=AAPL, quantity=3), Position(id=null, ticker=NIO, quantity=3)])])
 Saved portfolio : Portfolio(id=1, ownerEmail=jasiekziom@gmail.com, roomId=1, startingCash=1000.0, states=[PortfolioState(id=2, fromDate=2020-01-01 00:00:00.0, to=Mon Jan 06 00:00:00 CET 2020, cash=300.0, positions=[Position(id=3, ticker=MSFT, quantity=2), Position(id=4, ticker=AAPL, quantity=3)]), PortfolioState(id=5, fromDate=null, to=null, cash=null, positions=null)])
 Portfolio object  after saving Portfolio(id=1, ownerEmail=jasiekziom@gmail.com, roomId=1, startingCash=1000.0, states=[PortfolioState(id=2, fromDate=2020-01-01 00:00:00.0, to=Mon Jan 06 00:00:00 CET 2020, cash=300.0, positions=[Position(id=3, ticker=MSFT, quantity=2), Position(id=4, ticker=AAPL, quantity=3)]), PortfolioState(id=5, fromDate=null, to=null, cash=null, positions=null)])
```

I've tried fixing this issue by using CascadeType.MERGE along with PERSIST, but it results in states duplicating. I'm using h2-in-memory database and plain JPA without hibernate. I'm using a default save method from JPARepository interface.
Can you explain what and why is happening ? How do i fix this ?

Comment: Just to clarify: Are all the objects new and they should be persisted? Do you insert the ids manually before persisting them? BTW: Consider to [change the fetch type to lazy](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/). Also, a [unidirectional `@OneToMany` might not be the best idea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). Consider to change it to bidirectional `@OneToMany` or just a unidirectional `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: @FelixSeifert  Portfolio is an an already existing object that has been fetched from DB with all it's children. The code ran above `System.out.println(" Portfolio : " + portfolio.toString())` creates a new PortfolioState and add's it to the Portfolio.states. I'll apply your tips get back to you.

Comment: When the portfolio object does already exist, it might not cascade the changes to save its children. You just set `CascadeType.PERSIST`, i.e. the persist action is only cascaded to the children if the parent object itself gets persisted. `FetchType.EAGER` is not the reason for this (see your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FelixSeifert helped me figured out this one. It seems that `FetchType.EAGER` was causing the problem. I've switched to `FetchType.LAZY` and `CascadeType.ALL`. I've also added a bidirectional `@ManyToOne` in *PortfolioState.java*.

```
public class Portfolio implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        private String ownerEmail;

        private Long roomId;

        private Double startingCash;

        @OneToMany(
                cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
                orphanRemoval = true
        )
        private List<PortfolioState> states = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
public class PortfolioState implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Date fromDate;

    private Date to;

    private Double cash;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Position> positions = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Portfolio portfolio;

}
```